# invalid web service call

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webservice-client

I have a web service that works & I call from JS.
When I call it from a test console app, I get the error:

InvalidOperationException: Invalid web service call, expected path info of /js/{Method>'. Editor does not like opening lt sign before method.

I'm trying to see what is missing. I'm passing a json string.
This is my first time using HTTPClient.
Thanks
Abbott

```
// This is the js setup logic
function kboLoadImages() {
    var isbn = $("#kboIsbnValue").val();

    var ajaxCallParams = new KboAjaxCallParams(_kboVerifyStoreImagesOnServer,
        _kboVerifyStoreImagesOnServer);
    ajaxCallParams.Data = isbn;
    kbo_JsonQuery(_kboAjaxBaseUrl, _kboVerifyStoreImagesOnServer,
        ajaxCallParams, _kboBlockWindowClose);
}
```

```
// The service call
function kbo_JsonQuery(url, method, ajaxCallParams, allowWindowClose) {
    if (_kboAjaxIsActive) return; // prevent double clicks - racing
    _kboAjaxIsActive = true;
    var jsonString = "{ 'ajaxCallParams': " + JSON.stringify(ajaxCallParams) + " }";
    var myUrl = url + method;
    //kbo_showModalOverlay();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myUrl,
        data: jsonString,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: allowWindowClose, //blocks window close
        success: kbo_Success,
        error: kbo_Error
    });
}
```

```cs
// The console call
static string CallWebAPI(string isbn)
{
    var _kboAjaxBaseUrl = "KboAjaxBase.asmx/";
    var _kboVerifyStoreImagesOnServer = "VerifyStoreImagesOnServer";
    var uri = "https://kidsbookoutlet.com/";
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var ajaxCallParams = new AjaxCallParams();
        ajaxCallParams.PageType = _kboVerifyStoreImagesOnServer;
        ajaxCallParams.Request = _kboVerifyStoreImagesOnServer;
        ajaxCallParams.Data = isbn;
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri + _kboAjaxBaseUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var content = new StringContent(ajaxCallParams.GetState(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, content).Result;
        var responseText = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        AjaxCallParams returnParams = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AjaxCallParams>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

        return returnParams.Data.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see the working url in the js code but the url in the c# code does not seem to obey the pattern that the error message is demanding ?

Comment: so it means that the POST request you create from console app is not the same as from JS app. If you have such possibility I reccomend you to use 3rd party app to diagnose web traffic i.e *Fiddler*. Then you will be able to compare both requests and find the difference. (it could be headers, or you add params in wrong format etc)

Comment: Can you show me how your `JSON` string looks like?

Comment: I followed the suggestion to use fiddler and found 2 issues: the uri did not include the service function name and the json built by my function included and extra level of hierarchy. 
I want to thank you all for your prods and suggestions.
Abbott